# A question concerning Schwartz subspaces with some zero derivatives at the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $S$ denote the space of *Schwartz functions* and for $d , n=1,2,3,\ldots $
define
$$ 
S_{\emptyset ,n}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right) =\left\{ \phi \in S\left( 
\mathbb{R}^{d}\right) :D^{\alpha }\phi \left( 0\right) =0,\quad \left\vert
\alpha \right\vert <n\right\},
$$
where I have used standard multi-index notation and $n$ can be referred to as the *order*.

**My first question is**: Is the pointwise function product space
$S_{\emptyset ,n}S_{\emptyset ,n}$ a vector space?

It is not difficult to show that $S_{\emptyset ,n}S_{\emptyset ,n}\subset
S_{\emptyset ,2n}$ and a **related question is**: Under what conditions
is a function in $S_{\emptyset ,2n}$ a member of $S_{\emptyset
,n}S_{\emptyset ,n}$?

**I think a good first step** would be to consider the case $n=d=1$. In this case
$$
S_{\emptyset ,1}\left( \mathbb{R}^{1}\right) =\left\{ \phi \in S\left( 
\mathbb{R}^{1}\right) :\phi \left( 0\right) =0\right\},
$$

and I now ask: Is the pointwise function product space 
$$
S_{\emptyset ,1}\left( \mathbb{R}^{1}\right) S_{\emptyset ,1}\left( \mathbb{R%
}^{1}\right) :=\left\{ \sigma \in S\left( \mathbb{R}^{1}\right) :\sigma
\left( x\right) =\psi \left( x\right) \phi \left( x\right) ,\quad \psi ,\phi
\in S_{\emptyset ,1}\left( \mathbb{R}^{1}\right) \right\} ,
$$
a vector space?

Finally, it is known that $S = SS$ e.g. Google "Weil-Schwartz envelopes for rapidly decreasing functions." on the Web.

Comment: I think that $D^\alpha \phi(0) = 0$ is equivalent to $\phi = x^\alpha \psi$ for some $\psi \in S.$